# Does anyone know how to debug javascript in IE 7 and IE 8 using Visual Studio Express 2010 without having to install Frontpage Server extensions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, internet-explorer, debugging

I want to use visual studio express to debug Javascript in IE7/8, but it seem to require that frontpage server extensions to be installed on the page.

Answer (score -1):

Internet Explorer 8 offers a developer tools menu option that gives you an error console. I would Highly recommend using it. if you get it working in IE8 it will most likely work in 7. To get to the menu look in tools or press f12.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The F12 tools in IE7 don't allow you to debug anything, only log information. The tools for IE9 and IE8 are significantly better but don't work in IE7.